# How to insert in visual block on different columns

Tags: vim

Imagine I have this lines:

```
one_view = Column(String(5))
two_view = Column(String(5))
three_view = Column(String(5))
four_view = Column(String(5))
five_view = Column(String(5))
six_view = Column(String(5))
seven_view = Column(String(5))
eight_view = Column(String(5))
nine_view = Column(String(5))
```

I need to append `_f` after each `view`.

I'm entering visual block and doing `8j`, after this I want to find the first occurrence of `=` in each line and put the cursor here, after this I want to enter insert mode.

Is it possible with vanilla vim?

Edit: I know I can do it with macros or with `:s/view/view_f/g` but I'm just interested is it possible this way

Comment: You've already accepted an answer, but I'll note that you might want to look into vim `macros`. Those are my go-to in situations like this. If everything didn't end in `view`, or the word `view` was somewhere else in your file, you'd have issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, visual block mode can't be used that way.

Generally, visual block mode creates a *rectangle*, which implies columns and vertical alignment. The only case where visual block mode is not restricted to vertically aligned text is when expanding the block to the end of the line with `$` and, even then, it's only the end of the lines that is concerned.

`:[range]s/view/&_f` is *really* the best approach, here.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. Not answering the actual question, but for that kind on things I would use one of those strategies:

- use a substitution, like `s/_view/_view_f/` in the right scope
- align all the spaces (with [easyalign](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) for instance) and then use visual mode and `I` to insert `_f` on a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, it wouldn't work as you've described it with vanilla vim (There are some align plugins which might actually make it possible, but I really don't recommend that for many reasons) I'd recommend using `macros` over regex. The regex is only going to work for this specific case. If 'view' wasn't there, it wouldn't work (Maybe you could then regex off of  `=`, but you're not really setting yourself up well long term. This type of thing comes up all the time, and I prefer `macros`. These let you copy a number of commands and replay them. So you'll create a macro that does the first one, then you will replay the macro 8 times to do the other 9. So I would:

1. `gg` to get to the top of this nine line file
2. `qq` start a macro bound to `q`
3. `e` to get to the end of the first word
4. `a_f` to append `_f` to the first word
5. `Esc` to exit insert mode
6. `j` to go to the next line
7. `0` to go to the beginning of the line
8. `q` to end your macro
9. `8@q` to play `q` the macro 8 times.

Now your file should look how you'd like.

Comment: Well… the regex doesn't have to be specific. `:[range]s/\>/_f` works just as well without assuming `view`. It's really just a matter of what flows the easiest depending on the situation. And FWIW, what you described is actually a recording; macros don't *have* to be used that way. `:[range]norm ea_f` would be a much less ceremonial and more efficient way to use a macro in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the time to add some feedback. I feel there's always something new to learn. For me there are many real world situations that are more complex than this question where I'm copying portions of variable names, pasting, function calls over multiple lines, etc. and recording complex macros and being able to play them many times at once is a very versatile tool that I use all the time. But there are many situations like this that come up, and I'd never thought of doing it like this, so thanks.